# Combining match patterns into a single pass

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching

Can someone tell me what algorithms, academic papers, frameworks I could use to allow a single pass over data with arbitrary amount of match patterns?

Comment: What kind of patterns are we talking about? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm?

Comment: There are [lexer/scanner generators](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Lexer_generator).

Comment: Please give an example of the kind of data you're dealing with, as well as a bunch of examples of patterns that you might want to match against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any [regular grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), i.e. matches that can be described without referring to other parts of the input (such as matching brackets), can be implemented as a [deterministic finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) and matched very efficiently in one pass. Multiple regular expressions/finite automata can be merged using the [powerset construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) algorithm (by treating the input DFAs as NFAs).

As for more complex matches that need [context-free grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), algorithms generally need only one top-to-bottom pass. However, some algorithms require backtracking i.e. rewinding guesses, therefore reading part of the input more than once (possible several times). Specifically, if your grammar can be written as [LR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser), it can be parsed without backtracking, otherwise a backtracking [LL parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) will be needed.

You'll find more specific information in [this post.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/65915/what-is-the-big-o-worst-case-upper-bound-for-time-and-space-requirement-of-the)